Weird issues with passing an XML file using Get-Content into Get-WinEvent
Having a weird issue (if I could event call it that). Not very well versed in Powershell/C#. I've tried looking up this problem with no luck. Here is a short script:
CD C:\Windows\System32
Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content "Admin.xml")) | Select-Object Level, LevelDisplayName, @{n='TimeCreated';e={Get-Date ($_.TimeCreated) -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}, ProviderName, Id, Task, Message, LogName, UserId, TaskDisplayName | export-csv "C:\Scripts\EventCollector_.csv" -UseCulture –NoTypeInformation

I run this script to collect application logs from Event Viewer using an XML file called "Admin.xml" in the system32 folder. Whenever I run it I get the following errors:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> cd C:\Scripts
PS C:\Scripts> .\eventcollector.ps1
Get-WinEvent : The description string for parameter reference (%1) could not be found
At C:\Scripts\EventCollector.ps1:2 char:1
+ Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content "Admin.xml")) | Select-Obj ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The description string for parameter reference (%1) could not be found,Microsoft.PowerSh
   ell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

Get-WinEvent : The description string for parameter reference (%1) could not be found
At C:\Scripts\EventCollector.ps1:2 char:1
+ Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content "Admin.xml")) | Select-Obj ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The description string for parameter reference (%1) could not be found,Microsoft.PowerSh
   ell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

Get-WinEvent : The description string for parameter reference (%1) could not be found
At C:\Scripts\EventCollector.ps1:2 char:1
+ Get-WinEvent -FilterXml ([xml](Get-Content "Admin.xml")) | Select-Obj ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The description string for parameter reference (%1) could not be found,Microsoft.PowerSh
   ell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

I get these errors in the console, but The output .csv still populates properly. So I'm not too sure if it's just skipping over whatever throws this error?
This is running on an up-to-date Windows 2022 Server. I tried running the script on Windows 2016 and Windows 2019 servers, and get no errors.
Is this something I should be worried about? Or is it not a problem?
If it isn't a problem, how can I get the errors to stop showing up?

Do these log messages contain unsanitized user input for some reason? The problem is not on your end, it's the fault of whoever writes the messages to the event log in the first place - they wrote the literal string value %%1 somewhere in a message payload, which in turn is interpreted as a macro during generation of the Message property value (event log messages are template-based, not actually stored as-is in most log entries)

What does the xml look like?

Wow -filterxml example 16 in the get-winevent docs with "<=" doesn't even work.

Use <= instead of <=.  "get-content -raw" works with -filterxml.
